# Freak memory issue in pandas Grouper

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very strange memory leak in python/pandas. My code is very large and complex, but the essence is that I run 8 large (10 million lines) pandas dataframes in a loop, each time doing a resample, so 8 iterations. The dataframe has **timestamp index**. The memory is sufficient for the first four or five iterations - process memory goes up and down to the low level, but suddenly in the fifth iteration the memory use explodes to 1.5 Gb and the code breaks with MemoryError. I clean the variables as much as possible in between, so the memory is stable the first few iterations.

Is it possible that python fails garbage collection at some point in some cases and not others?

```
frequencyString = '5T'
for mydataframe in dataframes:
    ...
    mydataframe.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=frequencyString)).min()
    ...
```

Comment: for huge dataframes, I run my groupby with dash http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/. Dask is cool because it uses pandas dateframe and your dataframe don't have to fit in your RAM like pandas

Comment: Thanks, will try dask, but that does not "plug" the leak, it shouldn't happen in my view.

Comment: What happens if you do fifth iteraion separately?

Comment: Runs smoothly, without any problem!

Comment: Solved in the end: the problem was a bit of code run with `exec` between the lines. Although I didn't find documentation describing memory allocation during exec statements, I suspect python creates duplicates of existing local variables and after finishing the work does not fully return memory back to the OS. Repeated exec statements then create a memory issue.